# How to add a result count in exposed filters?

Tags: 8, views

For theming purposes, I need to display the views results in the exposed form.  Right now, through the UI, it's easy to add "Global: Result summary" to the views header, section.  But how would one display it within the exposed form?

Answer (score 3):

There's no use trying to use hook_form_alter, as you need to wait until the view is rendered.  You can do this in hook_preprocess_views_view__VIEWNAME like this:

```
function examplemodule_preprocess_views_view__exampleview(&$variables) {
  $result = $variables['header']['result'];
  unset($variables['header']['result']);
  $variables['exposed']['result'] = $result;
}
```